# laser scanner suitable for outdoor

Tags: ros, laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi

I want to know where I can find all the laser scanner that is compatible with ROS? and it must be able to use in outdoor, and will not be effected by the sunlight.

edit: plz any one can give me some name at least nothing else , I need to know what is suitable for outdoor and compatible with ROS.

I hope any one can help me with this.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261523/laser-scanner-suitable-for-outdoor/) by [ghaith](https://answers.ros.org/users/26984/ghaith/) on ROS Answers with karma: 89 on 2017-05-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hokuyo's UTM30 series is generally quite good outdoors, and they're well supported by the urg_node package. I've had issues with the smaller URG-04LX outdoors.

I'm not as familiar with the SICK lidars, but I've heard they also work well outdoors.

If you want a multiline laser scanner, Velodyne's VLP-16 works well outdoors too, and has reasonable ROS support.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-05-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ghaith](https://answers.ros.org/users/26984/ghaith/) on 2017-05-13**:
thanks a lot for the answer and for the helpful information.